# Como retornar uma lista de cada capítulo?

Tags: c#

Segue arquivo texto:

```
@MATEUS (1)
1 Livro da genealogia de Jesus Cristo, filho de Davi, filho de Abraão.
2 A Abraão nasceu Isaque; a Isaque nasceu Jacó; a Jacó nasceram Judá e seus irmãos;
3 a Judá nasceram, de Tamar, Farés e Zará; a Farés nasceu Esrom; a Esrom nasceu Arão;
4 a Arão nasceu Aminadabe; a Aminadabe nasceu Nasom; a Nasom nasceu Salmom;
5 a Salmom nasceu, de Raabe, Booz; a Booz nasceu, de Rute, Obede; a Obede nasceu Jessé;
6 e a Jessé nasceu o rei Davi. A Davi nasceu Salomão da que fora mulher de Urias;
7 a Salomão nasceu Roboão; a Roboão nasceu Abias; a Abias nasceu Asafe;
8 a Asafe nasceu Josafá; a Josafá nasceu Jorão; a Jorão nasceu Ozias;
9 a Ozias nasceu Joatão; a Joatão nasceu Acaz; a Acaz nasceu Ezequias;
10 a Ezequias nasceu Manassés; a Manassés nasceu Amom; a Amom nasceu Josias;
11 a Josias nasceram Jeconias e seus irmãos, no tempo da deportação para Babilônia.
12 Depois da deportação para Babilônia nasceu a Jeconias, Salatiel; a Salatiel nasceu Zorobabel;
13 a Zorobabel nasceu Abiúde; a Abiúde nasceu Eliaquim; a Eliaquim nasceu Azor;
14 a Azor nasceu Sadoque; a Sadoque nasceu Aquim; a Aquim nasceu Eliúde;
15 a Eliúde nasceu Eleazar; a Eleazar nasceu Matã; a Matã nasceu Jacó;
16 e a Jacó nasceu José, marido de Maria, da qual nasceu JESUS, que se chama Cristo.
17 De sorte que todas as gerações, desde Abraão até Davi, são catorze gerações; e desde Davi até a deportação para Babilônia, catorze gerações; e desde a deportação para Babilônia até o Cristo, catorze gerações.
18 Ora, o nascimento de Jesus Cristo foi assim: Estando Maria, sua mãe, desposada com José, antes de se ajuntarem, ela se achou ter concebido do Espírito Santo.
19 E como José, seu esposo, era justo, e não a queria infamar, intentou deixá-la secretamente.
20 E, projetando ele isso, eis que em sonho lhe apareceu um anjo do Senhor, dizendo: José, filho de Davi, não temas receber a Maria, tua mulher, pois o que nela se gerou é do Espírito Santo;
21 ela dará à luz um filho, a quem chamarás JESUS; porque ele salvará o seu povo dos seus pecados.
22 Ora, tudo isso aconteceu para que se cumprisse o que fora dito da parte do Senhor pelo profeta:
23 Eis que a virgem conceberá e dará à luz um filho, o qual será chamado EMANUEL, que traduzido é: Deus conosco.
24 E José, tendo despertado do sono, fez como o anjo do Senhor lhe ordenara, e recebeu sua mulher;
25 e não a conheceu enquanto ela não deu à luz um filho; e pôs-lhe o nome de JESUS.
@MATEUS (2)
1 Tendo, pois, nascido Jesus em Belém da Judéia, no tempo do rei Herodes, eis que vieram do oriente a Jerusalém uns magos que perguntavam:
2 Onde está aquele que é nascido rei dos judeus? pois do oriente vimos a sua estrela e viemos adorá-lo.
3 O rei Herodes, ouvindo isso, perturbou-se, e com ele toda a Jerusalém;
4 e, reunindo todos os principais sacerdotes e os escribas do povo, perguntava-lhes onde havia de nascer o Cristo.
ETC...
```

Como retornar uma lista de cada capítulo ?

Exemplo:

Dentro de `@MATEUS (1)` retorna 25 listas

Dentro de `@MATEUS (2)` retorna 4 listas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<List<String>> capitulos = new List<List<String>>();
StreamReader arquivo = new StreamReader("meuarquivo.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
while((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if(linha.StartsWith("@MATEUS")) {
        // cria o novo capitulo, que é uma lista de versículos
        capitulos.Add(New List<String>());
    } else {
        // adiciona um versículo no último capitulo criado
        capitulos.Last().Add(linha);
    }
}  

file.Close();
```

Na minha implementação, um capítulo é uma lista de versículos. Ao ler linha-a-linha, se a linha atual começa com `@MATEUS`, então tenho que criar um novo capítulo. Se não começar por `@MATEUS`, adiciono o versículo ao último capítulo da lista `capitulos`.

Pode parecer estranho uma lista de listas de `string`. Mas veja que um capítulo é uma coleção de versículos. Vários capítulos podem ser representados como uma coleção de coleção de versículos.

Se você quer saber quantos versículos tem Mateus 1, por exemplo, pode fazer:

```
capitulos[0].Count();
```

- [Método StreamReader.ReadLine (System.IO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: vnbrs, como posso retornar todos livros com seu capitulos e versiculos, porque dentro de uma pasta tenho vários blocos de notas, cade seu bloco de nota tem seu livro.

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma: `List<List<List<String>>> livros = new List<List<List<String>>>();` não funcionou.

Comment: Pode criar uma nova pergunta @MatheusMiranda?

Comment: Vou criar, aguarde.

Comment: post criado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261887/como-retornar-array-string-de-cada-livro-com-seu-cap%C3%ADtlos-e-vers%C3%ADculos