# Como mudar um texto específico de um arquivo txt?

Tags: c#, txt

No meu bloco de nota tem 2620 linhas que é o máximo.

```
>PRODUTO [1]
1. Exemplo de texto 1
2. Exemplo de texto 2
>PRODUTO [2]
1. Exemplo de texto 1
2. Exemplo de texto 22
>PRODUTO [3]
1. Exemplo de texto 1
2. Exemplo de texto 2
3. Exemplo de texto 3
```

**@lazyFox**: Como é que você está lendo o ficheiro?

```
public void Ler_TXT()
{
    string linha = string.Empty;
    List<List<String>> texto = new List<List<String>>();
    StreamReader arquivo = new StreamReader($@"C:\Minha Pasta\MeuTexto.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

    while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (linha.StartsWith($">PRODUTO"))
        {
            texto.Add(new List<String>());
        }
        else
        {
            texto.Last().Add(linha);
        }
    }
}
```

<del>É possível mudar um texto específico sem reescrever o texto todo?</del>

Pode ver que na linha : `2. Exemplo de texto 22` está com número "2" a mais. Como eu posso mudar texto específico. Eu tenho o valor `"PRODUTO [2]"` e tenho valor `"2."`, como posso fazer isso em C# ?

Comment: Como é que você está lendo o ficheiro?

Comment: @lazyFox aguarde, vou editar pergunta.

Comment: Já agora se gerou esse ficheiro por código coloque também a "escrita"

Comment: isso me parece bem pontual, talvez fosse melhor fazer no notepad++ com um macro por exemplo. E de qualquer forma, teria que reescrever o arquivo todo de novo, só o fato de ler e salvar o arquivo já estaria reescrevendo ele

Comment: @lazyFox eu não gero arquivo pela lógica, é um txt baixado na internet (Já vem pronto).

Comment: @RovannLinhalis 2620 linhas não é muito para reescrever o texto todo?

Comment: @lazyFox pergunta editada.

Comment: Sim  você terá de reescrever o ficheiro todo de qualquer modo, mas com 2620 linhas é um ficheiro relativamente pequeno.

Comment: @lazyFox tudo bem, porque esse arquivo é maior que eu tenho, os demais são menor que 2620 linhas.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, você quer ler o arquivo e remover todos os dígitos repetidos dentro de um `>Produto [n]`?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Não, atualizar apenas uma linha, porque eu já tenho valor `PRODUTO [2]` e `2.` armazenado na memória. Porque ás vezes vem um palavra errada, daí eu quero corrigir.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Como você pretende encontrar a linha? Pelo índice, pelo conteúdo, regex ou outra opção?

Comment: @LINQ  pelo conteúdo já é suficiente.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Por que você faz a leitura do arquivo daquela forma? Acho que eu não entendi bem o que você está fazendo... Você tem o arquivo pronto e quer fazer esta correção, certo?

Comment: @LINQ aqui tem a resposta porque eu fiz a leitura do arquivo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245852/54019 e Sim quero fazer esta correção apenas uma linha.